# How to gather two NSDictionary and add to NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I am currently programming check-in application. I am trying to gather all check-in details to NSUserDefaults with using NSDictionary. I have this code block;

```
NSMutableDictionary *oldcheckin =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"MissionID"];
            if([oldcheckin valueForKey:@"CheckinID"]) // I don't know how to take last object CheckinID value
            {
                int number = [[oldcheckin valueForKey:@"CheckinID"] intValue] +1;
                NSMutableDictionary *newcheckin= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",number], @"CheckinID",dateRightLabel.text, @"Date", noteLabel.text, @"Note",typeLabel.text, @"TypeID",projectLabel.text, @"ProjectID",noteLabel.text, @"Note", longitute, @"Longitute",latitude, @"Latitude",nil];
            }
            else
            {
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1", @"CheckinID",dateRightLabel.text, @"Date", noteLabel.text, @"Note",typeLabel.text, @"TypeID",projectLabel.text, @"ProjectID",noteLabel.text, @"Note", longitute, @"Longitute",latitude, @"Latitude",nil] forKey:@"MissionID"];
                 NSDictionary * myDictionary = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"MissionID"];
                 NSLog(@"%@",myDictionary);

            }
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

It is easy to add first NSDictionary to NSUserDefaults. Yet, it is hard to take before NSDictionary values and collect with new check-in values. For example, I have added first time these values to NSUserDefaults using code block which is given above.

```
{
CheckinID = 1;
Date = "2016.09.19 21:15";
Latitude = "37.33233141";
Longitute = "-122.03121860";
Note = "test";
ProjectID = "2";
TypeID = "1";
}
```

When I want to add another check-in details, I need to take old check-in details and gather with new check-in details. For example;

```
{
CheckinID = 1;
Date = "2016.09.19 21:15";
Latitude = "37.33233141";
Longitute = "-122.03121860";
Note = "test";
ProjectID = "2";
TypeID = "1";
},
{
CheckinID = 2;
Date = "2016.09.20 21:15";
Latitude = "35.33233141";
Longitute = "120.03121860";
Note = "test2";
ProjectID = "5";
TypeID = "4";
}
```

Something like that, after I need to take each check-in details. By the way, CheckinID will be incremental on by one as last checkinID. Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the dictionaries to the array and save the array into the dictionary.

```
[myArray addObject:oldcheckin];

 NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [userDefaults setObject:myArray forKey:@"myDictArray"];
```

then to retrieve it,

```
 NSMutableArray *arrayOfDicts = [[userDefaults objectForKey:@"myDictArray"]mutableCopy];
```

and add the new dictionary to the array

```
 [arrayOfDicts addObject: newcheckin];
```

and save the new array in user defaults.

Comment: @vadian you are right. I updated my answer.Thanks for pointing it out.